# Multiple Plots over non-consecutive integer parameter values

Tags: plotting, summation

The following is a simple illustration of the difficulty I have encountered with multiple plots on the same diagram. The reason for trying to overcome (understand) the difficulty is more involved and is clarified after the illustration.

Consider two definitions of the same function as follows:

```
g[m_] = m E^(-m x^2)

gi[n_Integer] = n E^(-n x^2)
```

A plot of `g[m]` for several values of m simultaneously is possible with

```
Plot[g[m] /. m -> {1, 2, 3}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which results in

[image: multiple plot gm1]    or    [image: with Evaluate gm2],

using `Evaluate[g[m] /. m -> {1, 2, 3}, {x, -3, 3}]` for the latter.

The same application of the `Plot` function, however, does not work with the second definition

```
Plot[gi[n] /. n -> {1, 2, 3}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Inserting `Evaluate[g[m] /. m -> {1, 2, 3}, {x, -3, 3}]` makes a difference and will make  the plot lines distinct, however it still does not work with the second function `gi[n]`, so I have left it out for simplicity.

The questions:

1. What causes the difference in plotting `g[m_]` and `gi[n_Iinteger]` as above?
2. How can Plot work with the second function definition
   `gi[n_Integer]`, just as it does with the first `g[m_]`?

Clarification:
I am aware of other methods for producing multiple plots in one diagram, such as constructing lists with Table and similar. The reason for pursuing the above approach for multiple plots with a list of values for a parameter, specified as in `gi[n_Iinteger]`, is the possibility to extract non-consecutive terms from solutions of differential equations in the form of a sum. In the following example from the Mathematica Documentation

```
eqn = I  D[\[Psi][x, t], t] == -2 D[\[Psi][x, t], {x, 2}];
f[x_] := -350 + 155 x - 22 x^2 + x^3
sol = DSolve[{eqn, \[Psi][5, t] == 0, \[Psi][10, t] == 0, \[Psi][x, 2] == f[x]}, \[Psi], {x, t}]
```

the solution is a function as an infinite sum

[image: Psi solution],

from which a partial sum is extracted with

```
u[k_Integer] = \[Psi] /. Activate[First[sol] /. \[Infinity] -> k]
```

The above function is used to produce multiple plots with Table

```
...Table[Plot[{u[k][x, 2], f[x]}, {x, 5, 10}, ImageSize -> 200], {k, 4}]...
```

however, the plots are for consecutive values of k and not readily adaptable for extraction of individual terms and sums for non-consecutive k-values. Therefore, the summary question is

3. How can multiple plots be accomplished as illustrated for `g[m_]` above with a function specified as `u[k_Integer]`?

I shall be grateful for any help with these questions.

Clarification edit shifting emphasis to question 3. as the ultimate goal:

The first comment by Bob Hanlon suggested one successful approach to question 2., using Map (thank you Bob)! Unfortunately, I was unable to apply the same method to `u[k_Integer]` above - question 3. Consequently, I'd be grateful for responses related to the latter.

Comment: Correct the spelling of `Integer` then `Map` the function onto the values. `Plot[Evaluate[gi /@ {1, 2, 3}], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thank you Bob! Map worked with gi, however I was unsuccessful with applying it to `u[k_Integer]` in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = I D[ψ[x, t], t] == -2 D[ψ[x, t], {x, 2}];
f[x_] := -350 + 155 x - 22 x^2 + x^3
sol = DSolve[{eqn, ψ[5, t] == 0, ψ[10, t] == 0, ψ[x, 2] == 
     f[x]}, ψ, {x, t}];

u[k_Integer?Positive] = ψ /. Activate[First[sol] /. ∞ -> k];
```

For `k = {2, 4, 7}`

```
Plot[Evaluate[u[#][x, 2] & /@ {2, 4, 7}], {x, 5, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{2, 4, 7}, LegendLabel -> k],
   {.7, .65}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {x, HoldForm[u[k][x, 2]]})]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For two parameters

```
u2[k1_Integer?Positive, k2_Integer?Positive] = ψ /. 
   Activate[First[sol] /. 
     {{K[1], 1, Infinity} :> {K[1], k1, k2}}];

kValues = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {3, 7}};

Plot[Evaluate[u2[#[[1]], #[[2]]][x, 2] & /@ kValues],
 {x, 5, 10},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[ToString /@ kValues,
    LegendLabel -> {Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2]}],
   {.2, .3}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, 
     HoldForm[u2[Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2]][x, 2]]})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Bob! This is clear and completes the answer quite well. If I am not overstepping the kindness of your efforts, would you, please, help with extending for two parameters, `u[k1_Integer,k2_integer]`, specifically how to present two lists at the mapping `/@` accordingly. The purpose is to be able to specify arbitrary sets of values for the lower and upper limits of the solution sum. Gratefully -

Comment: Or you could use `Evaluate[(u2 @@ #)[x, 2] & /@ kValues]`

Comment: That’s absolutely great. Not only it does the job beautifully, I learned a lot, too. Wonderful help!

Answer (score 3):

Consider: g[m] /. m -> {1, 2, 3} This will evaluate to: g[{1,2,3}] and further: {1, 2, 3} E^(-{1, 2, 3} x^2) and finally to: {E^-x^2, 2 E^(-2 x^2), 3 E^(-3 x^2)}

However, gi[n] /. n -> {1, 2, 3} evaluates only to: gi[{1, 2, 3}] and it can not evaluete further because {1,2,3}has a head: List and not "Integer".

If you want to use gi[n] /. n -> {1, 2, 3}, you must give gi the attribute "Listable"

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SetAttributes[gi, Listable];
gi[n_Integer] = n E^(-n x^2);
Plot[Evaluate[gi[n] /. n -> {1, 2, 3}], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**addendum**

The third question is a bit more complex because you have 2 variables and the functions are complex. To make a simple example I will plot the Abs value and define u[k,t,x]:

```
SetAttributes[u, Listable]
u[k_Integer, t_, 
  x_] := (\[Psi] /. Activate[First[sol] /. \[Infinity] -> k] )[t, x]

Plot3D[Evaluate@Abs[u[{1, 2}, x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. Not only it works but also helped me understand the significance of Listable in this situation. Appreciated

Comment: Apologies for returning to the discussion. Just for completeness, what would be the reason for the SetAtribute to Listable approach, you suggested to work with the gi and not for the u[k_Integer] as in the context of my 3rd question? At least I could not make it work.

Comment: Look at the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give your function Attribute Listable.

```
g[m_] = m E^(-m x^2)

gi[n_Integer] = n E^(-n x^2)

Attributes[gi] = {Listable}

gi[n] /. n -> {2, 3, 4}  

gi[{2, 3, 4}]   (*  both yield   *)

(*   {2 E^(-2 x^2), 3 E^(-3 x^2), 4 E^(-4 x^2)}   *)
```

Many build in functions have this attribute.

```
Attributes[Sin]
```

If you don't do, or cancel it again, with Replace you get the whole list as argument of gi, which is not an Integer.

```
Attributes[gi] = {}

gi[n] /. n -> {2, 3, 4}

(*   gi[{2, 3, 4}]   *)
```

Without a restriction for argument like _Integer, function g is per se Listable   g[{2, 3, 4}]. But

```
 Attributes[g]    (*   {}   *)
```

does not show it. Don't know why?

Comment: Thanks Akku14. It is a complementary helpful perspective to the `Listable` approach.